# Extract part of string based on nth instance of character

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find a way to extract part of the strings below. I need everything between the 6th and 7th `\` character.

```
\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerA\Tlog\DBA1_TLOG_20110504_0333.SLS
\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerB\Tlog\model_TLOG_20120321_1038.SLS
\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Saturday\ServerA\TLog\DBA_2_TLOG_20120811_1538.SLS
\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Friday\ServerB\Tlog\DB3_TLOG_20120914_2330.BAK
\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerC\Tlog\DB44_TLOG_20120815_1445.BAK
```

Desired results:

```
ServerA
ServerB
ServerA
ServerB
ServerC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, one way would be to use an ordered split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStringsOrdered
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(2000),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(32)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN 
    (
      SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number), Item 
        FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
          CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)))
        FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
          FROM sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
        WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
      ) AS y);
```

Sample usage:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(filepath NVARCHAR(2000));

INSERT @x VALUES
('\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerA\Tlog\DBA1_TLOG_20110504_0333.SLS'),
('\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerB\Tlog\model_TLOG_20120321_1038.SLS'),
('\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Saturday\ServerA\TLog\DBA_2_TLOG_20120811_1538.SLS'),
('\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Friday\ServerB\Tlog\DB3_TLOG_20120914_2330.BAK'),
('\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerC\Tlog\DB44_TLOG_20120815_1445.BAK');

SELECT x.filepath, s.Item FROM @x AS x
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStringsOrdered(x.filepath, '\') AS s
  WHERE s.rn = 7;
```

Results:

```
filepath                                     Item
-------------------------------------------  -------
\\file...eed\Wednesday\ServerA\Tlog\DBA1...  ServerA
\\file...eed\Wednesday\ServerB\Tlog\mode...  ServerB
\\file...eed\Saturday\ServerA\TLog\DBA_2...  ServerA
\\file...eed\Friday\ServerB\Tlog\DB3_TLO...  ServerB
\\file...eed\Wednesday\ServerC\Tlog\DB44...  ServerC
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use any functions for this. Just some string manipulation.

Sample data

```
create table tbl (path varchar(1000));
insert tbl values (
'\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerA\Tlog\DBA1_TLOG_20110504_0333.SLS'),(
'\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerB\Tlog\model_TLOG_20120321_1038.SLS'),(
'\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Saturday\ServerA\TLog\DBA_2_TLOG_20120811_1538.SLS'),(
'\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Friday\ServerB\Tlog\DB3_TLOG_20120914_2330.BAK'),(
'\\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerC\Tlog\DB44_TLOG_20120815_1445.BAK');
```

**Query**:

```
select path, ltrim(rtrim(
                 substring(
                         replace(cast(path as nvarchar(max)),
                                 '\',
                                 replicate(cast(' ' as nvarchar(max)),10000)),
                         60001, 10000)))
  from Tbl
```

**Results**:

```
|                                                                           PATH | COLUMN_1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  \\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerA\Tlog\DBA1_TLOG_20110504_0333.SLS |  ServerA |
| \\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerB\Tlog\model_TLOG_20120321_1038.SLS |  ServerB |
|  \\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Saturday\ServerA\TLog\DBA_2_TLOG_20120811_1538.SLS |  ServerA |
|      \\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Friday\ServerB\Tlog\DB3_TLOG_20120914_2330.BAK |  ServerB |
|  \\fileServerA\d$\LiteSpeed\Wednesday\ServerC\Tlog\DB44_TLOG_20120815_1445.BAK |  ServerC |
```

Some notes:

1. String functions in SQL Server return the same type as their operands. You may notice that I cast both the `path` column and the space (' ') to nvarchar(max). Without these explicit casts, both would be truncated at 4000 characters - similar to the [STUFF issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788735/sql-server-stuff-is-it-supposed-to-work-with-position-8000).
2. The trick I am using makes use of the fact that spaces are not significant and can easily be removed using RTRIM+LTRIM. The spaces are made really large and form "walls" that effectively partition the data into "columns". The 7th column starts from 60001 (and a bit).

Comment: This method scales much better, but I have encountered problems with the large size of the columns. If you are using this method more than twice in a WHERE clause it starts negatively impacting performance, and the more you use, the worse it gets. I found that by shortening the values in REPLICATE and SUBSTRING by a factor of 100 (remove 2 0s) really helped the performance and still got me the desired results. Thanks very much for this solution.